# ODBC Driver upgrade 13-> X - SQL Server 2016 Agent stops working

Tags: sql-server, odbc, driver

When uninstalling the ODBC Driver 13(13.0.1501.5) and installing ODBC Driver 17 or 18, the SQL Server Agent stops working and the service is not starting at all.

We have a Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU17-GDR) 13.0.5893.48 (X64), where the main goal is to upgrade the ODBC driver and make SQL use the new one and not the old.

- We have tried to install both ODBC driver 17 and 18.
- We have tried to use the command Set-OdbcDriver "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
- We looked in logs.

[Here you have the errors shown in SSMS after I have uninstalled ODBC 13 and left with ODBC 17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0303P.png)

Comment: *"When uninstalling the ODBC Driver 13(13.0.1501.5)"* that was your mistake, reinstall the driver. You can't change the version of ODBC that SQL Server uses internally.

Comment: What is the specific problem in SQL Server you are trying to solve by upgrading the ODBC Driver version? SQL Server 2016 requires ODBC Driver 13.0 (or 13.1 if you're on SP1 or higher) so if you're trying to address ODBC vulnerabilities then the answer is upgrading to a newer version of SQL Server.

Comment: You can install new drivers side-by-side but do not uninstall the driver version installed by SQL Server components (SQL Server Agent, tools). SQL Server components use a specific driver version.

Comment: Thx for all your comments! I got the answers I needed and will work on getting the server upgraded because our main goal was to address the ODBC vulnerbilities, but as AlwaysLearning says, we need to upgrade the SQL server and it's not possible to use a newer version.

Comment: For what it's worth... if you had been keeping up-to-date on service packs, CUs and security updates then you could have installed [KB5021129 for SQL Server 2016 SP3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/kb5021129-description-of-the-security-update-for-sql-server-2016-sp3-gdr-february-14-2023-1a592815-9dc4-434b-9fb2-119339251317) back in February which included fixes for the ODBC Driver 13.x CVEs that you're probably concerned about.